# Same code executed on different servers (same version) yields different results

Tags: sql, delphi, sql-server-2012

Issue with Delphi legacy code. Added one line of code to correct one error and created a new error.

New error is causing the same executable to yield different results on different servers(switched the pointer from dev to prod environment on the executable).

code:

```
sEscapedString:=stringreplace(sStringIn,'[','''+char(27)+''[',[rfReplaceAll]);
sEscapedString:=stringreplace(sEscapedString,']','''+char(27)+'']',[rfReplaceAll]);
sEscapedString:=stringreplace(sEscapedString,'''','''''',[rfReplaceAll]);// this line created new 
bug
result:=' like ''' + Trim(sEscapedString) + '%'''+'  escape char(27) ';
```

When running the code against dev this query finds objects with the characters '[' and ']' in it
Against prod the query does not find those items:

The first thing I checked was the data: Exactly identical in both cases
The second thing I checked was SQL server versions (11.0.3128 on BOTH servers)
The third thing I am checking is settings on those servers:
    DBCC USEROPTIONS; -- same on both
    SELECT name, collation_Name FROM sys.databases -- same on both
    select @@OPTIONS -- same on both.
    Quoted identifiers are 'ON' for both servers

It comes down to the fact that I know one server is treating the escape character (chr(27)) differently than the other but I do knot know why.

Does anyone have a theory(or answer) as to why the 2 similar servers are treating the escape characters differently?

The goal here is getting the prod server to return values with '[' and ']', as setting up my system to work with the legacy code will take a LOT of additional time. I do have a fix for the code

```
sEscapedString:=stringreplace(sStringIn,'[','[[]',[rfReplaceAll]);
```

But the faster option would seem to be getting the server to read the values the same.

Update: We found the root cause of the difference and it was more mundane than what we expected, turns out the query we were running was actually executed twice. The second execution was missing the key piece on the production server.
The issue was resolved by moving the new line of code so that it executed first rather than last.

Comment: I feel a strong desire to add the `sql-injection` tag ;)

Comment: User is not allowed to enter data into this app, data comes from another table that is populated by a different app

Comment: How is the other table populated ?  If it's by a user then that's your sql-injection vector.  ;)

Comment: If there is SQL injection at this point, it is unintentional. The square brackets are valid input for the field, usually denoting a sub-object derived from another object (For Example: Object and Object[2], Object[2] is derived from Object). Plus the one server actually handles the query correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first try to find out if this SQL only causes different behaviour when it is sent from the application: by sending the SQL from an interactive SQL client tool to both servers.

To make sure that the manually tested SQL is exactly the same as in the application, I would try to log or capture the exact SQL as sent from the application as a text file and then paste its content to the SQL client tool.

If the server is the culprit, then using the SQL from a different client tool should cause the same difference with the two servers. If the client tool shows the same (correct) result on both servers, then something is going on in the Delphi application.

p.s. upvoted, it is an interesting phenomenon

Comment: I really wanted to use the trace to track exactly what was being sent to the server from the application, but I have been told the trace is off limits due to the extra overhead on the server, and the production server handles enough critical information they do not want to risk it. Thanks for the upvote, this is my current nightmare at work.